# How to find similar (but different) names with the same soundex value?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

[image][image: I want to select the soundex value S225 for the two names]

[image: This is what iried using this query but am not getting the exact result.]

I got the output with the *same* name and same `soundex` value, but I want the result which has *similar* name and same `soundex` value.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Please give some examples that you'd like to find.  How similar is similar?

Comment: And please do not post SQL statements as screen shots. Show the statements as **formatted** text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for this:

```
select *
from (
   select name, 
          count(*) over (partition by soundex(name)) as cnt
   from poi
) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: It Works......................
 Thank u so much ...a_horse_with_no_name.
then, what does the variable 't' stands for in that query?

Comment: @MohamedAshrafAliB it's not a variable but a mandatory table alias for a subquery.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name